# Hide options in option set without deleting it in MS CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

There are few options in option set in an entity in MS CRM 2011 which are not used frequently so I want to hide them. But I don't want to delete these because there are few records who had these values. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take time to understand and take a tour around to know how to ask a good question.

Comment: Honestly the best way of resolving this is to use Advanced Find to locate records using the old optionset values, and use bulk edit to update them. Then you can delete the old optionset values

Answer (score 3):

You cannot deactivate/hide the unused options from CRM picklist by customizations.

But we can write simple JavaScript to hide those values dynamically on formload, so users cannot choose them.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_samplefield").removeOption(1);
```

[Read more](http://crmdynamicblog.blogspot.com/2012/06/remove-item-from-picklist.html?m=1)

Comment: This answer won't work in CRM 2011, but it is correct for more current versions of CRM

Comment: @jasonscript the blog I given reference is for 2011. :)